# HTML5 audio tag - change source not auto playing

Tags: html, audio

I'm trying to change the current playing audio source. But it's not playing the song. After calling `audio.load()` a GET request is send for the resource, which result in a `HTTP 200 OK`. I tried settings an interval of 2 seconds before calling `audio.play()` but this doesn't solve my issue either. The console is not giving any error messages.

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" controls="controls" autoplay>
    <source id="audioSource" src="audio/myFirstSong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>



function updateSource(songName) {
    songName = "audio/" + escape(songName) + ".mp3";
    var audio = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

    var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
    source.src = songName;

    audio.load();//GET 200 OK
    audio.play(); //Doesn't play
    //Can't press the Play button in the controls either
}
```

Comment: Have you tried playing the url directly? The `controls="controls"` is more stable if you just use `controls` instead.

Comment: Yes the audio file plays when browsing to the URL. It also plays in windows media player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't change much of the original code:

- `controls="controls"` to `controls`
- The audio sources were changed
- Added a button and an event listener to call the `updateSource()` function.

I really don't see why my demo is that much different than yours -_-

http://plnkr.co/edit/GjYRjVqdRdCYSIUWuYoL?p=preview

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <audio id="audioPlayer" controls autoplay>
    <source id="audioSource" src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/fightclub.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  </audio>
  <button id="btn1">Update</button>

  <script>
    function updateSource(songName) {
      songName = "https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/" + escape(songName) + ".mp3";
      var audio = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

      var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
      source.src = songName;

      audio.load(); //GET 200 OK
      audio.play(); //Doesn't play
      //Can't press the Play button in the controls either
    }

    var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
    btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var songName = "pf-righteous";
      updateSource(songName);
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmm changed it to songName = "http://localhost:54643/audio/" + escape(songName) + ".mp3", still doesn't work for me. Your snippet works fine though.

Comment: The changes I did shouldn't make that much of a difference in functionality...perplexing.

Comment: @Reinard just by going by your code in a strict manner, the only thing I would say was your issue is that you didn't call `updateSource()` yet. Try adding `updateSource(songName)` after the function declaration.

Comment: I placed the mp3 files on a web server and it works now. Guess the issue is with visual studio/IIS express :s

Comment: I hear ya, VS is an overly complicated IDE. I never got into C++ because I dreaded using VS at the campus lab.